# Load assembly from binary array in Amazon lambda function by using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, aws-lambda

In my C# aws lambda function I use Assembly.Load() with a binary array. I do the following:

```
//
// "item" is an object that has the property "DotNetAssembly" with
// the binary array that has the assembly that I need to load
//
// this works perfectly!
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(item.DotNetAssembly)
```

Now I create an instance from the "assembly" variable:

```
//
// "item" is an object that has a property "DotNetType"
// with the name of the class that I need to instance
//
// this works perfectly!
var obj = assembly.CreateInstance(item.DotNetType);
```

But now, when I try to call the method "ABC" from the "obj" variable

```
//
// this doesn't work!
obj.ABC();
```

I receive the following error:
**System.MissingMethodException: Method not found "AmazonDynamoDBClient"**

The method "obj.ABC()" is using an instance of "AmazonDynamoDBClient", so it's clear that dotnet cannot resolve this dependency.

I found this Microsoft's article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading but it's not clear for me how to resolve dependencies when I use Assembly.Load(binary_array)

How can I resolve the dependencies that the variable "obj" or its class need?

Answer (score 0):

I found some information that could help you

**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=net-5.0

public static System.Reflection.Assembly Load (byte[] rawAssembly);

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.